# Offsetting Advanced Digitizing lines from north in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vector, digitizing, parallel-lines

In QGIS, I'm trying to draw some polygons (mostly rectangles) on a grid, with neat 90-degree right angles and such. All the polygons should be parallel or perpendicular to each other.

The problem is that the city I'm working on top of, Chicago, skews a little bit off a proper north-south line. For example, in the image below, Grant Park's field (yellow rectangle) is off just a bit from the red north-south line generated by Advanced Digitizing (and the red rectangle built from that line). Thus, anything I create off that red line won't match up with the park's grid.

Can I somehow "rotate" or "offset" the tool such that every line snaps to the yellow rectangle's lines, instead of compass north? If I add a bunch more red rectangles, their lines should all be parallel and perpendicular with the yellow one over Grant Park.

I tried rotating the entire QGIS canvas, but Advanced Digitizing still just points north-south. Or, if not through Advanced Digitizing, can I create my own guide/grid lines to snap other polygons to? Not really sure the proper way to do this.

[image: illustration]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify the angle of the first edge of the feature you're digitizing in Advanced Digitizing mode by digitizing the first point of your feature, pressing `a`, entering the desired angle, and pressing enter. After that, if angle snapping is activated and the "Relative angle" mode is active (use `Shift + a` to toggle if necessary), all edges will be drawn parallel or perpendicular to this first edge:

[image]

Unfortunately, the specification of the starting angle has to be repeated for each new feature - it would be nice if it were possible to specify a fixed angle offset. Consider opening a [feature request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/new/choose) for this.

Comment: Thank you! (And sorry for the slow response back). That was a very helpful explanation and animation. I didn't realize all those icons  and fields were actually UI elements (relative angle, inputting a specific angle, etc.)... thought they were just decorative elements.

One follow-up, if i may please: Is there a way to make the 4th corner perpendicular to BOTH the 1st and 3rd (e.g. 90 degrees to both)? I know I could've started with a rectangle shape, but that's not always possible for more complex polygons.

Comment: @i-know-nothing: I'm glad my answer was helpful. To ensure that the fourth corner is at a right angle to the first and third, you can use the self-snapping feature that's been introduced in QGIS 3.14. I use that approach in my animation: activate self-snapping (the button on the far right of the screen), draw the first three corners, then snap the angle of the third segment to 90° relative to the second segment, lock that angle, and (using Alt+a) and then snap to the first vertex. You can see another animation at https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/36200

Comment: Got it. Thank you again!